# Inner join of 2 tables on similar strings

Tags: mysql, join, case-when

I am looking for a way to do an INNER JOIN between 2 tables on a field that contain a similar string. Here are my 2 tables:

TABLE A

```
ID | Model              |   Item
1  | CALI FULL RELAX  | 3-SEAT-SOFA
2  | TOTO BREAK       | ARMCHAIR-BIS
3  |...                 | ...
```

TABLE B

```
IDbis | Modelbis | Itembis   | Image
1     | CALI     | SOFA      | 101.jpg
2     | TOTO     | ARMCHAIR  | 102.jpg
3     | TOTO     | SOFA      | 103.jpg
```

RESULTS would be:

TABLE C

```
Model | Item | Image
1  | CALI FULL RELAX  | 3-SEAT-SOFA | 101.jpg
2  | TOTO BREAK       | ARMCHAIR-BIS | 102.jpg
```

Comment: Have you tried using `like`. Maybe similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269803/mysql-join-on-like-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
SELECT A.MODEL AS MODEL, A.ITEM AS ITEM, B.IMAGE AS IMAGE FROM 
TABLE_A AS A INNER JOIN TABLE_B AS B ON A.MODEL LIKE CONCAT('%',B.MODELBIS,%');
```